# How can I fix a broken SLR Mirror?

Tags: repair, slr, mirror

I have an Olympus OM-1 which I've been using as a backup camera for my film Canon Rebel. However, when the mirror trap became stuck "up" in the Olympus, I tried gingerly to pull the trap back down. It eventually gave way and reset properly — but not before cracking and having pieces break away.

The camera still works great. The broken mirror doesn't mess with the viewfinder nearly as much as I thought it would, but it bothers me. Is it possible to repair this on my own? If so, how?

Comment: Next time try applying some [WD-40](http://www.wd40.com/) to the springs and movable parts. I've fixed a Pentax K1000 with the same problem by doing that.

Comment: @Andres The mirror isn't stuck - it's free and working. The mirror is cracked and fragmented.

Comment: I've re-read the question and edited my comment. Sorry, my native language isn't English and I misunderstood the question!

Comment: I'm tempted to tag this `seven-years-of-bad-luck`....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the age of the OM-1, it's a fair guess that the only way to get a replacement mirror would be to buy a junk OM-1 with a good mirror, and remove the mirror from one body and transplant it into the other. As you've already found, the mirror is *quite* fragile, so doing this would be fairly difficult.

Second, it's easy to find film cameras in *good* condition so cheaply that unless you're emotionally attached to this particular one, there's almost no point anyway.

Personally, I'd just use it as long as it works, and when/if it dies, decide whether to buy another, or consolidate to a single mount for both the main and backup body. Either way, any but the *very* most minor of repairs on a film camera is *extremely* difficult to justify anymore.

Answer (score 2):

#### It doesn't look good

(I'm jumping in because nobody else has answered)

**Short answer**: I would be very surprised if there were a feasible way to fix this at home.

To be fair, I am not a repair technician, so I could be wrong, but I don't think many photographers would want to risk it.

So, if you don't want to take it to an approved repair shop, I think you'll just have to get used to it as it is.

I'm sorry about that  :-(