# AF mirror not flipping on Canon 350D

Tags: repair, mirror, canon-350d

My Canon 350D is no longer raising the AF mirror when it takes a photo.  Instead, it looks like this when the mirror flips up.
[image: not swinging]

This results in a photo that is half black due to the sensor being obscured.

This camera is 9 years old and has never been dropped, mishandled or subjected to harsh temperature or humidity.  Is there any common maintenance I can do to get this thing swinging properly again?

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-slr-mirror?rq=1

Comment: Given the age of the camera, i think it would be best to just replace it with new model.

Comment: These are really two separate questions. The other one is about fixing a cracked mirror that still cycles up and down properly.

Answer (score 1):

Contact service or give it a rest. I understand how much you are unwilling to do so, but you should let a pro to fix your lovely camera.